# Need help tunneling Remote Desktop (RDP) over SSH using OpenSSH

Tags: remote-desktop, cygwin, putty, openssh, ssh-tunnel

So heres my set up. The picture isn't "Exact" I have modified it, but it gives you an idea.

[image]

The tools I am using are:

- `PUTTY`
- `OpenSSH`
- `CYGWIN`
- `Remote Desktop`
- `VMware vCenter Server Version 5.1.0`
- `vSphere Client Version 5.1.0`

Another thing I might note is that the machine `DEVILSMILK` and `DUCLAW` are Virtual Machines. `KENT-PC` is my physical machine with Administrative access to the domain where all 3 machines reside in the same local network `10.0.10.0/24`. Also here is a list of the Operating Systems running on each machine:

- `KENT-PC` - `Windows 7 Ultimate`
- `DEVILSMILK` - `CENTOS 6.3`
- `DUCLAW` - `Windows Server 2008 Datacenter`

Steps I've taken thus far with SSH:

- On `DEVILSMILK` I am running `OpenSSH` as my SSH server and have disabled `iptables` so all ports are open.
- On `DUCLAW` I am running `OpenSSH` via `CYGWIN` and rules have been made to allow access to `Remote Desktop` as well as port 22 for SSH.

My first machine `KENT-PC` at `10.0.10.110:RHP`(Random High Port) is SSH'd into `DEVILSMILK` at `10.0.10.113:22`. `DEVILSMILK` at `10.0.10.113:RHP` is SSH'd into `DUCLAW` at `10.0.10.130:22`.  All connections have been made successfully and are logged in.

SSH Tunneling Configurations on `PUTTY`:

- `KENT-PC` - `L33389 localhost:60666`
- `DEVILSMILK` - `L60666 localhost:3389`

Now with all these configurations set and SSH connected successfully from end to end I then initiate `Remote Desktop` from `KENT-PC` and try to connect to `localhost:33389`.

`Remote Desktop` should then attempt to connect to `KENT-PC` at at port `33389` which will then be forwarded to `DEVILSMILK` on port `60666` which is then forwarded to `DUCLAW` on port `3389` (Remote Desktop Port) and the connection should be established and it should work, and I will have tunneled `Remote Desktop` through an encrypted SSH tunnel.

But it doesn't.

The error I get from `Remote Desktop` is:

> This computer can't connect to the remote computer.
>
> Try connecting again.  If the problem continues, contact the owner of
>   the remote computer or your network administrator.

Couple other things to note.

Remote Desktop directly to `DUCLAW` works fine with no issues, it just doesn't work through the SSH Tunnel.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE 1: Tried changing all the tunnel port numbers and hostnames to:

- `KENT-PC` - `L62333 DEVILSMILK:62334`
- `DEVILSMILK` - `L62334 DUCLAW:3389`

Still doesn't work. Also disabled the firewall entirely on `KENT-PC`...no go.

UPDATE 2: Tried using IP addresses instead of hostnames and that didn't work either.  I also tried using port 3333 instead of 62333 for `KENT-PC` `Localhost` Tunnel port number and still the same.

Comment: On `KENT-PC`, can you connect to port 33389 with telnet? What does that say?

Comment: No I can't, it doesn't say anything. I turned off my firewall and then attempted to connect to 33389 with PUTTY on localhost from `KENT-PC` and the terminal window flashes and disappears.

Comment: Have you tried no tunnel or a single tunnel between a pair of {`KENT-PC`, `DEVILSMILK`, `DUCLAW`}? Can you connect to the RDP port itself from a remote machine, or from `DUCLAW` itself? What have you tried to isolate the problem? This problem seems very specific to your setup and is probably some configuration error. I'm not sure how helpful this is for others at [SU].

Comment: As I stated above: "`Remote Desktop` directly to `DUCLAW` works fine with no issues, it just doesn't work through the SSH Tunnel".  I can also `RDP` to `DEVILSMILK` just fine.  What I can do however is try to tunnel to `DEVILSMILK` and see if that works and try to isolate the problem a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently there was some sort of issue with using the `putty` GUI to do the first `SSH` from `Kent-PC` to `DEVILSMILK`.  A user on the /techsupport subreddit recommended that I use `CYGWIN` for all my machines.  Sure enough after installing `CYGWIN` and using these commands:

```
ssh -vg -L 3333:localhost:6666 misfitred@devilsmilk
```

Connection Established.

Then from the same SSH console.

```
ssh -vg -L 6666:localhost:3389 kgraves@duclaw
```

Connection Established.

Then Run this command from KENT-PC which is my original host:

```
mstsc /v:localhost:3333
```

And Wahlah! As you can see in the picture below `DUCLAW(10.0.10.130)` is being accessed via Remote Desktop and as you can see in Wireshark it is an encrypted SSH connection that appears as if it is coming from `DEVILSMILK (10.0.10.113)`.

I can now quit beating my head against the desk.  Thanks to all who helped figure this out.

[image]